# цикл в часте кода imacros

Tags: циклы, imacros

Подскажите нужен цикл например на 10 действий в куске кода Imacro.

начало скрипта

```
  TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:imacros-highlight-div&&TXT:
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:update_addon_rus_ruble_form ATTR=NAME:dispatch[currencies_sync.sync]
        TAB T=1
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:×
        BACK
        URL GOTO=https://yandex.ru


Начало цикла на 10 повторений
    TAG POS=16 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:
    TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Все
    TAG POS=6 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:manage_products_form ATTR=* CONTENT=NO
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Сохранить
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon<SP>icon-angle-right&&TXT:
Конец
```